# Spring BeanCreationException error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm studying STS Database connection.

and I try to connect with my local DB.

My HomeController.java :

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@Autowired private AccountRepository AccountRepository;

//@Autowired
//private AccountDaoImpl AccountDaoImpl;

//private AccountDao AccountDao;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homehome(Locale locale, Model model) {
    return "home";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Account> getUserList() {

    return AccountRepository.findAll();
    //EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit");
    //AccountDaoImpl.entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    //return AccountDaoImpl.getAccount();
}
//@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
//public String login(Locale locale, Model model) {
//  
//  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
//  return "login";
//}
}
```

AccountRepository.java :

```
@Service
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
}
```

My Account.java :

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Account")
 public class Account implements Serializable {
 @Id
 @Column(name = "email")
 private String email;
 @Column(name = "id")
 private String id;
 @Column(name = "password")
 private String password;

 public void setEmail(String email) {
     this.email = email;
 }

 public String getEmail() {
     return email;
 }

 public String getId() {
     return id;
 }

 public void setId(String id) {
     this.id = id;
 }

 public String getPassword() {
     return password;
 }

 public void setPassword(String password) {
     this.password = password;
 }
```

I think AccountRepository.java have @Service, but I get this error.

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   root cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myongjoon.spring.AccountRepository com.myongjoon.spring.HomeController.AccountRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myongjoon.spring.AccountRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>       org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>       javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   root cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myongjoon.spring.AccountRepository com.myongjoon.spring.HomeController.AccountRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myongjoon.spring.AccountRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>       javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   root cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myongjoon.spring.AccountRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>       javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Pivotal tc Runtime 3.1.2.RELEASE/8.0.26.B.RELEASE logs.
>
> Pivotal tc Runtime 3.1.2.RELEASE/8.0.26.B.RELEASE

I want to avoid this error.

what should I do?

Comment: BTW: You are doing Spring, not STS! STS (Spring Tool Suite) is just an IDE, but it is not the framework you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root case is: "No qualifying bean of type com.myongjoon.spring.AccountRepository found".

This is because, your code looks like you try to use Spring-Data-Jpa for your Repository. But this requires:

- that your repository is just an interface (without `@Service` annotation) 
  and
- you need to enable Spring-Data-Jpa, either by

  - `<springjpa:repositories base-package="com.your.repositories.package" />` (Namespace `springjpa` = `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd`) or
  - @EnableJpaRepositories("com.your.repositories.package")

@see: [Spring-Data-Jpa Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.spring)

Comment: thank you but I edit my code to package com.myongjoon.spring;
 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.myongjoon.spring")
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
} error stile occur. how can i avoid this error?

Comment: What do you mean by "error contents is not changed" - and of course you need to configure the right package names, `com.your.repositories.package` was just a placeholder.